# How to change the number of allowed concurrent endpoint calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

My SPA web client has a page that makes ~30 requests simulateously to the same (light) endpoint in my REST API (.Net ASP Core 6).

Currently, my configuration seems to only handle 5 concurrent requests at a time, the others are in a queue. The consequence is a very slow user experience and under usage of my server resources (CPU mainly).

I have not (as far as I understand it) configured anything explicitely. My guess is that 5 is the default setting.

The Host builder is using default values:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseSentry();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .UseNLog();  // Setup NLog for Dependency injection;
```

The `web.config` file does not have any specific config regarding the topic at hand:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My PUT endpoint is fairly basic:

```
[HttpPut("{id}/Foo")]
public async Task<ResultDto> GetFoo(int id, QueryDto query, CancellationToken cancellationToken) { ... }
```

I found lot of resources regarding [legacy ASP.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/asp/limits) but nothing of value for ASP Core 6 (eventhough [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468512/asp-net-core-max-concurrent-connections) confuses me)

How can I configure ASP Core to allow more concurrent requests of the same endpoint?

PS: I experience the same limitation to 5 concurrent requests in both `localhost` and when deployed on `Azure AppService` (linux).

Comment: There is nothing by default 'limiting' the amount of requests your asp.net core  (6) application can handle - the entire framework is designed to handle thousands of (concurrent) requests with very little threads. So usually means that you have a bottleneck elsewhere in your application. Have you tried seeing if having a basic endpoint returning a simple status code is also affected by this limit you're seeing?

Comment: The issue is likely to be with the implementation of your `GetFoo()` endpoint, which you've not provided the code for. The defaults for ASP.NET Core support a very high number of concurrent requests. Alternatively, the machine you're running the code on is of a limited specification or has poor networking.

Comment: Could it be related to the CPU core count of your computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments posted above by everyone, it appears it's not an API (ASP Core) issue.

The browsers have limited concurrent open connection count (to a given server).
There are [leads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477498/how-to-get-around-browsers-6-concurrent-connections-per-domain-limit) to avoid that behaviour.

The solution is also to rewrite my endpoint to have it pool the results instead of one-by-one and thus lower the amount of actual requests made by the frontend.